# AeadConfig.register() throws exception

Tags: tink

I am trying to use `tink` to encrypt data.

My initialization routine is as follows:

```
        try {
            AeadConfig.register();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is throwing an exception:

```
tried to access field com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.memoizedSize from class com.google.crypto.tink.proto.HmacKeyFormat
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.memoizedSize from class com.google.crypto.tink.proto.HmacKeyFormat
    at com.google.crypto.tink.proto.HmacKeyFormat.getSerializedSize(HmacKeyFormat.java:182)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.toByteArray(AbstractMessageLite.java:62)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.Registry.registerKeyTemplates(Registry.java:653)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.Registry.registerKeyManager(Registry.java:556)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.mac.HmacKeyManager.register(HmacKeyManager.java:232)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.mac.MacConfig.register(MacConfig.java:86)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.mac.MacConfig.init(MacConfig.java:74)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.mac.MacConfig.<clinit>(MacConfig.java:59)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.aead.AeadConfig.register(AeadConfig.java:102)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.aead.AeadConfig.init(AeadConfig.java:86)
    at com.google.crypto.tink.aead.AeadConfig.<clinit>(AeadConfig.java:68)
    at com.zillow.kafka.message.MessageEncryptor.<init>(MessageEncryptor.java:24)
    at com.zillow.kafka.message.MessageEncryptorTest.testSimple(MessageEncryptorTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
```

here is my gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = "https://packages.confluent.io/maven"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java' // so that we can use 'implementation', 'testImplementation' for dependencies
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = "https://packages.confluent.io/maven"
    }
    maven {
        url = "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.avro:avro-tools:1.9.0'
    // Kafka
    implementation "org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:2.2.0"
    implementation 'org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.0'
    implementation 'io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:6.2.1'
    implementation 'io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:6.2.1'
    implementation 'io.confluent:kafka-json-serializer:6.2.1'
    implementation 'io.confluent:kafka-json-schema-provider:6.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.6.1'

    //test
    testImplementation(platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.0'))
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter')
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
        }

        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/avro", "src/main/resources"]
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/test/java"]
        }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}

plugins.withId("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"){

    //this block requires the java plugin to be applied first.
    plugins.withId("java"){

        shadowJar {
            //We are overriding the default jar to be the shadow jar
            classifier = null
            exclude 'META-INF'
            exclude 'META-INF/*.INF'
            exclude 'META-INF/license/*'
        }

        jar {
            manifest {
                attributes(
                        'Built-By'       : System.properties['user.name'],
                        'Build-Timestamp': new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format(new Date()),
                        'Created-By'     : "Gradle ${gradle.gradleVersion}",
                        'Build-Jdk'      : "${System.properties['java.version']} (${System.properties['java.vendor']} ${System.properties['java.vm.version']})",
                        'Build-OS'       : "${System.properties['os.name']} ${System.properties['os.arch']} ${System.properties['os.version']}" ,
                )
            }
        }

        tasks.build.dependsOn tasks.shadowJar
        tasks.shadowJar.mustRunAfter tasks.jar
    }


}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

[EDIT] I saw in a google search that somebody else hit the same problem, and it was due to a conflicting version of protobuf on the classpath. However, in my case there is no conflicting version. I verified using `gradle dependencies`

```
+--- com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.6.1
|    +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.14.0
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6
```

Answer (score 0):

nvm.. this was happening because my intellij project import was corrupted.

removing it and reimporting the gradle project fixed the problem.